# Let $A$ be non singular, prove that $\frac{1}{\|A^{-1}\|} = \min_{\|x\| = 1} \|Ax\|$

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-norms

Let $A$ be non singular, prove that $\frac{1}{\|A^{-1}\|} = \min_{\|x\| = 1} \|Ax\|$

I know that $\|A\| = \sup_{\|x\| = 1} \|Ax\|$

but I have no idea how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help to grasp the idea:
$$
\begin{split}
\|A^{-1}\|
&=
\max_{x\neq 0}\frac{\|A^{-1}x\|}{\|x\|}
=
\max_{y\neq 0}\frac{\|y\|}{\|Ay\|}
=
\left(\min_{y\neq 0}\frac{\|Ay\|}{\|y\|}\right)^{-1}.
\end{split}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$\|A\|$ equals to the largest singular value of $A$. Since $A$ is nonsingular, all singular values are nonzero. Hence, the singular values of $A^{-1}$ are the inverses of the singular values of $A$. Therefore, $\|A^{-1}\|$ is the inverse of the smallest singular value of $A$.

Sine $\min_{\|x\|=1}\|Ax\|$ is the smallest singular value of $A$, the equality holds!

More precisely, assume that $\newcommand{\reals}{{\mathbf R}} A\in \reals^{n\times n}$. Suppose that $A=U\Sigma V^T$ is the singular value decomposition of $A$ with $U^TU = V^TV = I_n$, $\newcommand{\diag}{{\bf diag}}\diag(\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_n)$ and $\sigma_1\geq \sigma_2 \geq \cdots \geq \sigma_n$. Since $\sigma_i$ are singular values, $\sigma_i\geq0$. Since $\newcommand{\det}{{\bf det}}|\det A| = |\det(U)||\det(\Sigma)||\det(V)| = |\sigma_1 \cdots \sigma_n|$, nonsingularity of $A$ implies that $\sigma_i > 0$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$.

Now
\begin{eqnarray}
\|A\|
&=& \sup_{\|x\|=1}\|Ax\|
= \sup_{\|x\|=1}\sqrt{\|Ax\|^2}
= \sup_{\|x\|=1}\sqrt{x^TA^TAx}
= \sup_{\|x\|=1}\sqrt{x^TA^TAx}
\\
&=&
\sup_{\|x\|=1}\sqrt{x^TV\Sigma U^T U\Sigma V^Tx}
\\
&=&
\sup_{\|x\|=1}\sqrt{x^TV\Sigma^2V^Tx}
\\
&=&
\sup_{\|x\|=1} \|\Sigma V^Tx\|
\\
&=&
\sup_{y=V^Tx,\ \|x\|=1} \|\Sigma y\|
\\
&=&
\sup_{\|y\|=1} \|\Sigma y\|
\\
&=&
\sup_{\|y\|=1} \sqrt{\sigma_1^2 y_1^2 + \cdots + \sigma_n^2 y_n^2}
\end{eqnarray}
since $\|y\|^2 = y^T y = x^T V V^T x = x^T x = \|x\|^2$.
Now
\begin{equation}
\sigma_1^2 y_1^2 + \cdots + \sigma_n^2 y_n^2
\leq \sigma_1^2 y_1^2 + \cdots + \sigma_1^2 y_n^2 = \sigma_1^2 \|y\|^2 = \sigma_1^2
\end{equation}
with the equality achieved when $y_1=1$ and $y_2=\cdots=y_n = 0$.
Therefore
\begin{equation}
\|A\| = \sigma_1,
\end{equation}
i.e., $\|A\|$ equals to the largest singular value of $A$.
Therefore
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\|A^{-1}\|}
= \frac{1}{1/\sigma_n}
= \sigma_n,
\end{equation}
i.e., the smallest singular value.

Now the same derivation as before gives
\begin{equation}
\inf_{\|x\|=1} \|Ax\| = \inf_{\|y\|=1} \|\Sigma y\|.
\end{equation}
Since
\begin{equation}
\sigma_1^2 y_1^2 + \cdots + \sigma_n^2 y_n^2
\geq \sigma_1^2 y_n^2 + \cdots + \sigma_n^2 y_n^2 = \sigma_n^2 \|y\|^2 = \sigma_n^2
\end{equation}
with the equality achieved with $y_1=\cdots=y_{n-1}=0$ and $y_n=1$,
\begin{equation}
\inf_{\|x\|=1} \|Ax\| = \sigma_n,
\end{equation}
hence the proof!

Answer (score 0):

Let $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\|v\|=1$. Then $$1=\|v\|=\|A^{-1}Av\|\leq \|A^{-1}\|\|Av\|$$ This means $\frac{1}{\|A^{-1}\|}$ is a lower bound of $\{\|Av\|:\|v\|=1\}$. Thus $\frac{1}{\|A^{-1}\|}\leq\inf_{\|x\|=1}\|Ax\|$. On the other hand, $$\begin{eqnarray} 1 &=& \|v\|  \\ &=& \|Av\| \cdot \Bigg\|A^{-1}\Bigg(\frac{Av}{\|Av\|}\Bigg)\Bigg\| \\& \geq & \inf_{\|x\|=1}\|Ax\|\cdot \Bigg\|A^{-1}\Bigg(\frac{Av}{\|Av\|}\Bigg)\Bigg\|\end{eqnarray}$$ Since $u\mapsto \frac{Au}{\|Au\|}$ is a surjection on $S^{n-1}$ we see $\frac{1}{\inf_{\|x\|=1}\|Ax\|}$ is an upper bound of $\{\|A^{-1}v\|:\|v\|=1\}$. Thus $$\|A^{-1}\|\leq \frac{1}{\inf_{\|x\|=1}\|Ax\|} \iff \inf_{\|x\|=1}\|Ax\|\leq \frac{1}{\|A^{-1}\|}$$ The result follows.